# Matrix Calculation Different between Python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I am transferring a finite element analysis code from Matlab to Python.

A problem occurs at the last step when I try to solve the displacement U = F/K.
I have checked that the calculated F and K are same for Matlab and Python. However the resulting U are different.When the matrix size reach to 19684*19684，significant figures will be totally different, even the sign will be opposite.

My question is for the same K and F matrix, why Python and MATLAB would resulted in different answers for U = F/K. It is noted that if the size of K and F are small (e.g. 1000* 1000,1000* 1), the resulting U = F/K are very close from using Python & MATLAB. However, if the size of the two matrixes is larger, the resulting U would be quite different.

Can anyone suggest what's the problem here and how can I solve it?

Below are the codes for Matlab and Python.

#### Matlab

```
clear all; clc; close all
nelx=80; 
nely=80; 
beta = 1;
eta = 0.47;
volrate=0.20; 
E0 = 1;
Emin = 0.000001;
nu = 0.3;
a = 0.005;
b = 0.005;
h = 0.01;
q = -0.001;
penal = 3;
[KE1]= ElementStiffness(E0,nu,a,b,h);
TM3 = zeros(nely,nelx);
TM4 = zeros(nely+1,nelx+1);
TM3 = TM3+0.01;
% TM4([98:101 199:202 300:303 401:404]) = 0.01;
TM4([1]) = 0.01;
T2 = zeros((nely+1)*(nelx+1),1); 
num = 0;
for i=1:nely+1
    for j =1:nelx+1
        num = num+1;
        T2(num,1) = TM4(j,i);
    end
end
xTilde = repmat(volrate,[nely nelx]);
xPhys = ((tanh(beta*eta)+tanh(beta*(xTilde-eta)))/(tanh(beta*eta)+tanh(beta*(1-eta))));


K=sparse(3*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),3*(nelx+1)*(nely+1)); 
F=sparse(3*(nely+1)*(nelx+1),1);
U1=sparse(3*(nely+1)*(nelx+1),1); 

Fe=q*a*b*[1 b/3 -a/3 1 b/3 a/3 1 -b/3 a/3 1 -b/3 -a/3]'; 

for ely=1:nely 
    for elx=1:nelx 
        n1 = (nely+1)*(elx-1)+ely;
        n2 = (nely+1)* elx +ely;
        edof = [3*n1+1; 3*n1+2; 3*n1+3;3*n2+1;3*n2+2;3*n2+3;3*n2-2;3*n2-1; 3*n2; 3*n1-2;3*n1-1; 3*n1];
        K(edof,edof)=K(edof,edof)+(Emin+(1-Emin)*xPhys(ely,elx)^penal)*KE1; 
        if TM3(ely,elx)>0 
            F(edof)=F(edof)+Fe;
        end
    end 
end 


dd = find(T2 == 0.01); %T2=0-fixed node
fixeddofs = [(dd-1)*3+1 (dd-1)*3+2 (dd-1)*3+3]; 
alldofs   =1:3*(nely+1)*(nelx+1); 
freedofs  =setdiff(alldofs,fixeddofs); 

U1(freedofs,:)=K(freedofs,freedofs)\F(freedofs,:); 
U1(fixeddofs,:)=0;
U1matlab = full(U1);

function [KE1]= ElementStiffness(E,nu,a,b,h)
syms x y 
N1  = (1 - x/a)*(1 - y/b)*(2 - x/a - y/b - (x/a)^2 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Nx1 = b*(1 - x/a)*(1 - y/b)*(1 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Ny1 =  - a*(1 - x/a)*(1 - y/b)*(1 - (x/a)^2)/8;
N2  = (1 + x/a)*(1 - y/b)*(2 + x/a - y/b - (x/a)^2 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Nx2 = b*(1 + x/a)*(1 - y/b)*(1 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Ny2 =   a*(1 + x/a)*(1 - y/b)*(1 - (x/a)^2)/8;
N3  = (1 + x/a)*(1 + y/b)*(2 + x/a + y/b - (x/a)^2 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Nx3 = -b*(1 + x/a)*(1 + y/b)*(1 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Ny3 =   a*(1 + x/a)*(1 + y/b)*(1 - (x/a)^2)/8;
N4  = (1 - x/a)*(1 + y/b)*(2 - x/a + y/b - (x/a)^2 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Nx4 = -b*(1 - x/a)*(1 + y/b)*(1 - (y/b)^2)/8;
Ny4 =  - a*(1 - x/a)*(1 + y/b)*(1 - (x/a)^2)/8;
N=[N1 Nx1 Ny1 N2 Nx2 Ny2 N3 Nx3 Ny3 N4 Nx4 Ny4];
B1=diff(N,x,2);
B2=diff(N,y,2);
B3=diff(N,x,y);
B=-[B1;B2;2*B3];
D = (E/(1-nu*nu))*[1, nu, 0 ; nu, 1, 0 ; 0, 0, (1-nu)/2];
BD = transpose(B)*D*B;
KE1=int(int(BD,x,-a,a),y,-b,b)*h^3/12;
KE1=double(KE1);
end
```

#### Python

```py
from __future__ import division 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from scipy import sparse

nelx=80
nely=80
VF = 0.2
beta = 1
eta = 0.47
penal = 3 
a = 0.005
b = 0.005
q = -0.001
Emin = 1e-6
TM3 = np.zeros((nely,nelx))
TM3 = TM3+0.01
TM4 = np.zeros((nely+1,nelx+1))
TM4[0,0] = 0.01
T2 = np.zeros(((nely+1)*(nelx+1),1))
num = 0
for i in range(nely+1):
    for j in range(nelx+1):       
        T2[num,0] = TM4[j,i]
        num = num+1
KE1 = [[ 9.67032967e-03,  2.23443223e-05, -2.23443223e-05,
    -4.17582418e-03,  5.12820513e-06, -1.95970696e-05,
    -1.31868132e-03,  7.87545788e-06, -7.87545788e-06,
    -4.17582418e-03,  1.95970696e-05, -5.12820513e-06],
   [ 2.23443223e-05,  1.39194139e-07, -2.74725275e-08,
     5.12820513e-06,  4.39560440e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
    -7.87545788e-06,  3.47985348e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
    -1.95970696e-05,  5.67765568e-08,  0.00000000e+00],
   [-2.23443223e-05, -2.74725275e-08,  1.39194139e-07,
     1.95970696e-05,  0.00000000e+00,  5.67765568e-08,
     7.87545788e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  3.47985348e-08,
    -5.12820513e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  4.39560440e-08],
   [-4.17582418e-03,  5.12820513e-06,  1.95970696e-05,
     9.67032967e-03,  2.23443223e-05,  2.23443223e-05,
    -4.17582418e-03,  1.95970696e-05,  5.12820513e-06,
    -1.31868132e-03,  7.87545788e-06,  7.87545788e-06],
   [ 5.12820513e-06,  4.39560440e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
     2.23443223e-05,  1.39194139e-07,  2.74725275e-08,
    -1.95970696e-05,  5.67765568e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
    -7.87545788e-06,  3.47985348e-08,  0.00000000e+00],
   [-1.95970696e-05,  0.00000000e+00,  5.67765568e-08,
     2.23443223e-05,  2.74725275e-08,  1.39194139e-07,
     5.12820513e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  4.39560440e-08,
    -7.87545788e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  3.47985348e-08],
   [-1.31868132e-03, -7.87545788e-06,  7.87545788e-06,
    -4.17582418e-03, -1.95970696e-05,  5.12820513e-06,
     9.67032967e-03, -2.23443223e-05,  2.23443223e-05,
    -4.17582418e-03, -5.12820513e-06,  1.95970696e-05],
   [ 7.87545788e-06,  3.47985348e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
     1.95970696e-05,  5.67765568e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
    -2.23443223e-05,  1.39194139e-07, -2.74725275e-08,
    -5.12820513e-06,  4.39560440e-08,  0.00000000e+00],
   [-7.87545788e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  3.47985348e-08,
     5.12820513e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  4.39560440e-08,
     2.23443223e-05, -2.74725275e-08,  1.39194139e-07,
    -1.95970696e-05,  0.00000000e+00,  5.67765568e-08],
   [-4.17582418e-03, -1.95970696e-05, -5.12820513e-06,
    -1.31868132e-03, -7.87545788e-06, -7.87545788e-06,
    -4.17582418e-03, -5.12820513e-06, -1.95970696e-05,
     9.67032967e-03, -2.23443223e-05, -2.23443223e-05],
   [ 1.95970696e-05,  5.67765568e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
     7.87545788e-06,  3.47985348e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
    -5.12820513e-06,  4.39560440e-08,  0.00000000e+00,
    -2.23443223e-05,  1.39194139e-07,  2.74725275e-08],
   [-5.12820513e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  4.39560440e-08,
     7.87545788e-06,  0.00000000e+00,  3.47985348e-08,
     1.95970696e-05,  0.00000000e+00,  5.67765568e-08,
    -2.23443223e-05,  2.74725275e-08,  1.39194139e-07]]     
KE1 = np.array(KE1)
xTilde = np.ones(nelx*nely)*VF
xPhys = ((np.tanh(beta*eta)+np.tanh(beta*(xTilde-eta)))/(np.tanh(beta*eta)+np.tanh(beta*(1-eta))))

K = np.zeros((3*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),3*(nelx+1)*(nely+1)))
F =np.zeros((3*(nely+1)*(nelx+1),1))
U1 = np.zeros((3*(nely+1)*(nelx+1),1))
Fe=q*a*b*np.mat([1,b/3,-a/3,1,b/3,a/3,1,-b/3,a/3,1,-b/3,-a/3]).T
xPhys=xPhys.reshape(nelx,nely)

for ely in range(nely):
    for elx in range(nelx):
        n1 = (nely+1)*(elx+1-1)+ely+1
        n2 = (nely+1)*(elx+1) +ely+1
        edof = [3*n1+1, 3*n1+2, 3*n1+3,3*n2+1,3*n2+2,3*n2+3,3*n2-2,3*n2-1, 3*n2, 3*n1-2,3*n1-1, 3*n1]
        edof = [m-1 for m in edof]
        indices = np.ix_(edof, edof)
        K[indices]=K[indices]+(Emin+(1-Emin)*xPhys[ely,elx]**penal)*KE1           
        F[edof,:]=F[edof,:]+Fe   
        
dd = np.where(T2 == 0.01)[0]        
fixeddofs = [(dd)*3+1,(dd)*3+2,(dd)*3+3]
fixeddofs = np.array(fixeddofs)-1  
alldofs = range(3*(nely+1)*(nelx+1))
freedofs =np.setdiff1d(alldofs,fixeddofs).tolist()
K = sparse.csc_matrix(K)
indices = np.ix_(freedofs, freedofs)
U1[freedofs,0]=spsolve(K[indices],F[freedofs,0])
U1[fixeddofs,:]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indexing of `K` and `F` are correct for both codes, the difference might be due to how MATLAB / scipy each solve the linear equation `Ax = B`.

MATLAB provides an in-depth documentation for their [`mldivide`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) function (aka. `\`). The most relevant to this case being [their algorithm for solving sparse matrices](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt42omx_head), which can decide to use different solvers depending on the input matrix. A great explanation on how `mldivide` works can also be found in [this question thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/in-matlab-what-differences-are-between-linsolve-and-mldivide#:%7E:text=mldivide%20for%20square%20matrices%3A%20If%20A%20is%20symmetric,to%20reduce%20the%20system%20to%20a%20triangular%20matrix.), which compares `mldivide` with [`linsolve`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html).

Meanwhile, scipy doesn't provide much explanation of what algorithm they are using behind the scene for [`spsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html), but it appears that they are using UMFPACK as the default solver

[From scipy's Github, line 189-190:](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L91-L241)

```
x = umf.linsolve(umfpack.UMFPACK_A, A, b_vec,autoTranspose=True)
```

I had a hard time finding the documentations for UMFPACK, but *it appears that UMFPACK then uses the LU solver.* Sources: [SuiteSparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html), [Scilab documentation](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/umfpack.html)

---

Using different solver methods would be able to explain the numerical differences of your two codes.

So depending on how significant the difference in results are, you may want to investigate deeper; specifically decide on what specific solver you need for your use case, and use those functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I see here is that in the 19684*19684 case your K matrix is probably nearly singular and/or badly scaled, hence the matrix division is done in the least-square sense, either by considering the More-Penrose pseudo-inverse or by maximizing the number of zero components of the solution. Python and Matlab may make a different choice here. You can check this by computing the numerical rank of K.